# Modeling a bounded function

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to model a **monotonic** function, that is bounded by y_min and y_max values, satisfies two value pairs (x0,y0), (x1,y1) within that range.

Is there some kind of package in python that might help in solving for the parameters for such a function?

Alternatively, if someone knows of a good source or paper on modeling such a function, I'd be much obliged...

(for anyone interested, i'm actually trying to model a market respons curve of a number of buyers vs. the price of a product, this is bounded by zero and the maximal demand)

Comment: it's not clear to me what you mean by "model".  do you want to fit the parameters of an analytic model to some data?  or do you just want some analytic model that meets those requirements (there are a lot...)?  what is the domain (x range)?

Comment: as far as I understand, he has a monotonic curve, starting from y_min going all the way up to y_max passing from (x0,y0) and (x1,y1). The question is, what are the parameters of the function? i.e. find the vector p for the curve y = p[0]*x^n + p[1]*x^(n-1) + p[2]*x^(n-2) ... p[n-1]*x + p[n]. The question is what shall be the grade/shape of your fitting function!

Comment: As per your question: I think you should firstly try spline interpolation of the data you have for number of buyers vs price of a product. I even doubt that is going to be monotonic since it is not sure that lower price will just always show the same trend. That is a model as far as I know. You are predicting one variable based on other. Now, for solving where the maxima and minima occurs, it is then easy to find. Your question is vague to suggest anything for now.

Comment: You're aware of numpy, right? I don't know if it has what you want, but it's the first place to look.

Comment: If you only have to fit two values, a linear function `f(x) = a*x+b` would do, wouldn't it? :-) It would by definition be monotonic too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well it's still not clear to me what you want, but the classic function of that form is the [sigmoid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SigmoidFunction.html) (it's used in neural nets, for example).  in a more flexible form that becomes the [general logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function) which will fit your (x,y) constraints with suitable parameters.  there's also [the gompertz curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_curve), which is similar.

however, those are all defined over an open domain and i doubt you have negative numbers of buyers.  if that's an issue (you may not care as they get very close to zero) you could try transforming the number of buyers (taking the log kind-of works, but only if you can have a fraction of a buyer...).

Comment: Thanks! I'll check those out.